# Why NULL is not the same as '\0'

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have the following code:

```
char alfabeto[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
                   'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};  

int i = 0;

printf("|");

do
{
    printf("%c |",alfabeto[i]);
    i++;
}while(alfabeto[i]!= '\0');
```

With NULL I get the following warning:

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default] in C
```

But with `'\0'` it compiles OK. I know which `'\0'` is used for terminating char strings and NULL is used for comparison with pointers. But do they not have the same value?

Comment: Note that your `alfabeto` character array is not null terminated (which means it isn't a string), so there is no guarantee about when the loop will terminate, or what garbage will be printed after `z`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most implementations NULL and `'\0'` have the same value: both are zero. The difference is in the data type: NULL is a pointer, while the other is an `int`. It doesn't really make sense to compare pointers with anything that's not a pointer, and that's why the compiler gives you a warning.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the literal `'\0'` is of type `int`.

Comment: Thanks @YuHao! The standard clearly says that _An integer character constant has type **int**._

Answer (score 2):

They have the same value, but are different in type.

- `\0` is the same as `0`
- `NULL` is implementation-defined, but usually the same as `(void*)0`.

You should always look towards using expressions with the right type.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` has `void*` as type, but `'\0'` is of type `int`.

`void*` are pointers, so 8 bytes on my machine. `int` is 4 bytes.

In C++ `'\0'` is a `char` of 1 byte